# Why does list labelling take the label name literally, and how to prevent this?

Tags: r, list

I am creating a list, and as I create the list the list elements need to have a label. (I am creating a list of Naive Bayes likelihood tables.)

Here is a simplified example of what I am doing:

```
list1 <- list()
names <- c("An", "example")

for (i in names){
    list1 <- append(list1, list(i = "hello"), after=length(list1))   
}
```

Output:

```
$i
[1] "hello"

$i
[1] "hello"
```

As you can see, the method I used to label the list element as 'i' took the 'i' literally, as opposed to interpretting it as it is in the for loop argument.

I've never come across this occurring within a for loop before.

**Questions**

Why is this happening?

What can I do to stop a literal interpretation of the iterator?

The output I would like to see is:

```
$"An"
[1] "hello"

$"example"
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: in `i = "hello"` your i is not related to the iterator, it is the name of the first argument you are passing to the `list()` function. So this is not a literal interpretation even. You could simply do `list1[[i]] <- "hello"` inside the for-loop

Comment: @RolandASc this looks like a comment that might make a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the OP's code, we can modify it to the set the names with 'i'

```
for (i in names){
   list1 <- append(list1, setNames(list("hello"), i), after=length(list1))   
}

list1
#$An
#[1] "hello"

#$example
#[1] "hello"
```

We don't need a loop though.  If we need to replicate a 'value' i.e 'hello', wrap it with `list`, use `rep` to replicate it and set the names with `setNames`

```
setNames(rep(list("hello"), 2), names)
#$An
#[1] "hello"

#$example
#[1] "hello"
```

---

In the OP's code, when we do the 'i = value', it just names the list element as 'i' instead of retrieving the value stored in the object

```
list(i = 1, i = 2)
#$i
#[1] 1

#$i
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this happening?

Because `list(i = "hello")` means "call the `list` function and provide the value `"hello"` to the parameter named `i`." So `i` is a name here, not a value.

> What can I do to stop a literal interpretation of the iterator?

Set the names from the start. Also, try to avoid growing vectors in `for` loops.

```
my_names <- c("An", "example")
list1 <- vector("list", length(my_names))
names(list1) <- my_names

for (i in my_names){
    list1[[i]] <- "hello"
}
```